# Simply safe internet access

Tags: firewall, iptables

Is it necessary to configure a firewall like iptables or firestarter
when the goal is only to surf safely?

For me, there is no need to open any port (i.e. samba, etc.).

Comment: Judging by the confusion in some answers below, I think you could improve your question by specifically stating what type of "safety" you're after. Are you interested in safety *and* anonymity?

Comment: From the FAQ: "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." It's my opinion that this question, most probably unintentionally, is too broadly scoped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need it if all you want to do is surf safe. However you can take the following steps:

- There are several add-ons available that can block NSFW content and ads.
- You can use a [proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) or a [VPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) to surf anonymously.
- You can use [TOR](http://www.torproject.org.in/) for some anonymity as well.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, the goal is not to surf anonymously, but deny things as pings, udp...

Comment: @Tim There's no need to accept an answer, if it doesn't answer your question (or at least help you towards an answer).

Comment: @Tim If you like an answer, you can upvote it; in fact, you can upvote many answers, but you can only accept one single answer; there's no rush in accepting, and you can also un-accept.

Answer (score 1):

If you're behind router and it uses network address translation (NAT) to share a single public IP assigned by your ISP, among computers in your LAN, I'd say you're pretty much safe and you don't need to set up addition firewall or iptables rules.

Because NAT, by default, will drop any unsolicated incoming traffic from the Internet when reaches your router. So in effect it also acts as a firewall that prevents incoming requests from reaching your computer

This also why when you need to access a service in your LAN from outside the network eg IP camera, you must set up a port forwarding on your router to allow the request to reach the service

Comment: [What are the risks of NOT using a firewall (home computer)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/263483/what-are-the-risks-of-not-using-a-firewall-home-computer)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Firefox (recommended), [**NoScript**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/) by Giorgio Maone is a great option worth considering!

The [NoScript website](http://noscript.net/) itself looks a bit messy; don't let that give you the wrong impression, though!

> The **NoScript Firefox extension** provides extra protection
>   for Firefox, Seamonkey and other mozilla-based browsers:  this free,
>   open source add-on allows **JavaScript, Java, Flash and other plugins**
>   to be executed only by **trusted web sites of your
>   choice** (e.g. your online bank).
>
> NoScript also provides
>   **the most powerful [anti-XSS](/features#xss) and anti-Clickjacking protection** ever
>   available in a browser.
>
> NoScript's unique **whitelist
>   based pre-emptive script blocking** approach  prevents
>   exploitation of **security vulnerabilities** (known and
>   **even not known yet**!) with no loss of functionality...
>
> You can enable JavaScript, Java and plugin execution for
>   sites you trust with a simple left-click on the **NoScript status bar
>   icon** (look at the picture), or  using the contextual
>   menu, for easier operation in popup statusbar-less windows.
>  Watch the "Block scripts in Firefox" video
>   by **cnet**.
>
> **Staying safe has never been
>   so easy!** 
>  Experts do agree...

Additionally, you may want to refer to [Should I use No-Script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33499/should-i-use-no-script)

Answer (score 0):

Here are simple iptables rules that are helpful to deny things as pings and other unwanted input connections:

```
 # Allows all loopback (lo0) traffic and drop all traffic to 127/8 that doesn't use lo0
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT

 # Accepts all established inbound connections
 -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

 # Allows all outbound traffic
 # You could modify this to only allow certain traffic
 -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
```

You will find more details [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo).